# Number of groups that can be formed

Tags: combinatorics

In a tennis tournament, there are $10$ players. In the first round, $5$ groups(of 2 players) will be formed among them and elimination matches will be held among the two players in each group. In how many ways can pairings be done?

Answer is given as : $\frac{10!}{2^5\times5!}$

My solution :

From $10$ players, we can select $2$ players in $\binom{10}{2}$ ways and form a group. From remaining $8$ players we can select $2$ players in $\binom{8}{2}$ ways and so on.

So, total number of pairings=$\binom{10}{2}\times\binom{8}{2}\times\binom{6}{2}\times\binom{4}{2}\times\binom{2}{2}=\frac{10!}{2^5}$

I want to know why the 5! in the answer should come. Any alternative solution will also be helpful.

Comment: The order you form your group doesn't matter. Then you are counting a selection of 5 groups 5! times.
If you don't see this, try to assign names (or numbers) to the players.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $5!$ comes from the order. You have picked $5$ groups, but you picked them in a certain order, eliminating $2$ at a time the $5!$ accounts for all possible orders of picking

Comment: Can you please explain it in a simpler manner?

Comment: you had choose 2 of 10, then choose 2 of 8, etc. But you multiplied them together, which gave 5 different pairings, which each could have occured in each of the 2 choose x statements, so the order doesnt matter, and you have to divide by $5!$

Answer (score 0):

If in your format you had match 1, match 2,...,match 5 and each was played at a different venue, then your answer would be correct. However this is not the case as you are only interested in sets of pairings. Suppose $A=\{1,2\} B=\{3,4\},...,D=\{9,10\}$ then one of the ways to obtain this set of pairings could be to draw $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$, similarly every permutation of the letters $A,B,C,D,E$ correspond to the same set of pairings. Finally there are $5!$ possible ways to permute the five pairs.